# how to update the whole column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my situation, I have a table called `Statuses` (`statusID, statusName`) with 22 statuses, and there are other tables that have `statusID` columns.

Now the customer wants to consolidate all the 22 statuses in the `Statuses` table into 13 statuses. Then we have to update, exactly speaking, map all `statusID` in all other tables.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: so you are looking to do a cascade update?

Comment: sql server 2008. I am think just write a script for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this sounds like a one time thing the easiest way is to hard code the map.

e.g.

```
UPDATE 
  TABLE
SET StatusID = CASE WHEN StatusID = 1 THEN 5
                    WHEN StatusID = 2 THEN 5
                    WHEN StatusID = 3 THEN 1
                    WHEN StatusID = 4 THEN 5
                    WHEN StatusID = 5 THEN 2
                    ...17 more times
               END
```

or if you already have a mapping table

```
UPDATE 
  TABLE
SET StatusID = map.NewStatusID
FROM
       TABLE as T
       INNER JOIN Map
       ON t.StatusID = map.OldStatusID
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use select query for the statusId? I have a mapping table StatusesMapping (OldStatusID, NewStatusID).

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I want. If the customer want to change the table later, all I need is to change the mapping table, not the script.

Comment: Out of interest why do you use an `INNER JOIN` for your inner query rather than a `SELECT...WHERE StatusID = map.OldStatusID`?

Comment: @jwg In this example it doesn't matter. But there are plenty of cases where does so by default I always use JOIN syntax. You can look at [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1018822) for more discussion on this

Comment: @ConradFrix thanks. I have come across the advantages of `INNER JOIN` in general queries, and I agree it is nice to use that syntax everywhere (once one is used to it).